# Selenium run time error

Tags: eclipse, selenium, runtime-error

I am getting this error while running selenium script.
[image]

Comment: paste your code in text format here along with exception.

Comment: Did you post your password?

Comment: Selenium version?

Comment: Selenium version is 3.13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
```

To :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks you So much the problem is solved and the code is running fine. But still getting some error at the console, though the script is running and executing.

Comment: Those exceptions are fine. That will not impact your execution though.